# How do You Track a Rouge Alarm?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, jodatime, android-alarms

I have this app release in Android that notifies the user everyday at specific time (for example 10:00 pm). I didn't use setRepeating as it **was not recommended** on higher APIs from 21 up. The following was the pseudo code I used to keep resetting the alarm.

```
AlarmController (set alarm)
Once time was met send to alarm receiver
Alarm receiver would call the Alarm Controller and Increase the day by 1 and set it again 
At the same time Alarm receiver will fire up the Intentservice for notification and set notified **true** in DataBase
```

In theory it was supposed to work. I am using Joda Time here to easily increase the day by 1. But the problem was, the notification kept firing up at a random time, sometimes it will fire up 6, after it was last fire up, or most often every 1 hour or 30 mins. I don't get it. Now the pseudo code I provided was the basic one. On my real code I have **two alarms**, one for firing up the notification and set Notified to **true** and the other was to **reset the notified to false** once the day change.

My app has been released. I never expected this scenario to happen because the way I debug this was on **genymotion**, I move the time manually and everything seems to be working alright. I had to fire a log on fabric IO but it seems that the log would only show once you get an error. Anyone thanks

Here is my bare minimum code that I was using exactly:

**Alarm Controller**

```
public static void setAdaptiveReminder(Context context, long ALARM_ID, DateTime dateTime, boolean shouldsetAlarm) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AdaptiveReminderReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("reminder", shouldsetAlarm);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) ALARM_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        ALARMMANAGER = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "setAdaptiveReminder: " + dateTime.toLocalTime().toString() + "  " + dateTime.toLocalDate().toString());

        CrashUtility.LogErrorReportToFabric(TAG + " setAdaptiveReminder", dateTime.toLocalTime().toString() + " " + dateTime.toLocalDate().toString());

        if (Utility.GetBuildVersion() >= 19 && Utility.GetBuildVersion() < 23) { // if lollipop
            //ALARMMANAGER.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000,1000,pendingIntent);

            ALARMMANAGER.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.toDate().getTime(), pendingIntent);
            //ALARMMANAGER.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,dateTime.toDate().getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

        } else if (Utility.GetBuildVersion() >= 23 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "setTimeSinceLastUseReminder:  android M and UP");
            ALARMMANAGER.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.toDate().getTime(), pendingIntent);
            //ALARMMANAGER.setrep(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,dateTime.toDate().getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
        }
}
```

**AlarmPresenter**

```
public void setAdaptiveReminder() {
        //AlarmController.setAdaptiveReminder(context,778,d);

        DateTime dateTime = TimeUtility.SetCorrectTimeInCorrectDate(settingsRepository.getAdaptiveReminderTime());
        boolean isNotified = settingsRepository.isNotifiedReminder();

        //Toast.makeText(context, "" + dateTime.toLocalTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.d(TAG, "setAdaptiveReminder: gggfss " + TimeUtility.DateIsToday(dateTime) + "  " + dateTime.toLocalTime().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "setAdaptiveReminder: " + isNotified);
        if (TimeUtility.DateIsToday(dateTime) && !isNotified) {
            dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(1);
            CrashUtility.LogErrorReportToFabric(TAG + " setAdaptiveReminder", dateTime.toLocalTime().toString() + " " + dateTime.toLocalDate().toString());
            AlarmController.setAdaptiveReminder(context, 778, dateTime, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "setAdaptiveReminder:  " + dateTime.toLocalDate() + "   " + dateTime.toLocalTime().toString());
        }
}
```

**Receiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        this.context = context;

        alarmControllerPresenter = new AlarmControllerPresenter(context,settingsRepository,habitRepository);
        alarmControllerPresenter.setAdaptiveReminder();

}
```

So the code I have provided was the exact same code I am using to set the alarm every day. I just did some cleaning up and that was about it.

Comment: If your are reseting the next alarm each time and have a problem with the next occurrence, you might need to should your code instead of a pseudo code. Especially if you are getting the alarm 1hour later instead of 1day...

Comment: Okay I will try to clean my code and post it.

Comment: Check how to provide a [mcve] first.

Comment: Hello, I have added my code